# JavaParser AnnotationExpr get parameters

Tags: java, parsing

I have an `AnnotationExpr`, how do I get parameters and their values of the annotation (e.g. `@UnityBridge(fullClassName = "test")` - how do I obtain a value of `fullClassName` parameter). Does JavaParser support this?

Do I have to accept another visitor? Which one in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Late answer, I came into the same problem, just cast the `AnnotationExpr` to one of following:

`MarkerAnnotationExpr` (for no parameter),

`SingleMemberAnnotationExpr` (for single parameter),

`NormalAnnotationExpr` (for multiple parameters).

You may need `instanceof` to determine current annotation type.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this approach without instanceof and searching children by type instead, although you still need a distinction for a single parameter without key to find the Parameter "value":

```java
private static final String VALUE = "value";

public static Expression getValueParameter(AnnotationExpr annotationExpr){
    Expression expression = getParamater(annotationExpr, VALUE);
    if(expression == null){
        List<Expression> children = annotationExpr.getChildNodesByType(Expression.class);
        if(!children.isEmpty()){
            expression = children.get(0);
        }
    }
    return expression;
}

public static Expression getParamater(AnnotationExpr annotationExpr, String parameterName){
    List<MemberValuePair>children = annotationExpr.getChildNodesByType(MemberValuePair.class);
    for(MemberValuePair memberValuePair : children){
        if(parameterName.equals(memberValuePair.getNameAsString())){
            return memberValuePair.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is:

```
import com.github.javaparser.StaticJavaParser
import com.github.javaparser.ast.CompilationUnit
import com.github.javaparser.ast.body.ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration
import com.github.javaparser.ast.expr.AnnotationExpr
import com.github.javaparser.ast.NodeList
import com.github.javaparser.ast.expr.MemberValuePair

// Annotation
public @interface AnnotationName {
  String argumentName();
}

// Class with this annotation
@AnnotationName(argumentName = "yourValue")
public class ClassWithAnnotationName {}

// Parse class with annotation
CompilationUnit compilationUnit = StaticJavaParser.parse(sourceFile);
Optional<ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration> classInterfaceForParse = compilationUnit.getInterfaceByName("ClassWithAnnotationName");

// Get annotation by name
final AnnotationExpr messageQueueKeyAnnotation =
        classInterfaceForParse.get().getAnnotationByName("AnnotationName").get();

// Get all parameters. It doesn't matter how many.
final NodeList<MemberValuePair> annotationParameters = messageQueueKeyAnnotation.toNormalAnnotationExpr().get().pairs;

// Read annotation parameter from the list of all parameters
final String argumentName = annotationParameters.get(0).value;
```